# Ubuntu & Gnome DPI Nightmare

Tags: gnome, resolution, dpi

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS in a machine I'm using attached to a TV. The thing is that when I plugged the USB for installation, I could not go straight away into installation, because the windows looked huge, not blurry, because the screen resolution was correct, huge as if put in a bigger size for that resolution. I had to go into Live mode, and from there start the installer for the system to recgognize the correct DPI for the TV.

The problem is that once finished the installation, when I am prompted with the log in screen, everything looks good, but once I am logged, I'm back to huge windows.

I've tried different options in different threads, but nothing seems to help. When I type `xrdb -query` in a terminal, this is the result:

```
*customization: -color
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:    192
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   rgb
```

But, when typing `xdpyinfo | grep resolution`, the result is this:

```
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

I tried with the gnome-tweak-tool, I tried putting a `77set_dpi` file into `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`, I tried with the command `xrandr --dpi 96x96`, but nothing changes the window size, and nothing changes the dpi value in `xrdb -query`.

Can anyone help?